# Canon DPP 4 - copy/apply white balance settings

Tags: canon, raw, white-balance, canon-dpp

I have two shots made with automatic white balance setup (AWB) in artificial light conditions. I like how the camera evaluated the white balance in the picture with white paw, I like how green color looks etc.

[image]

The second picture looks reddish. I tried to move micro-adjustment slider 7 points towards green but I don't like it as much as the first picture with default settings.

[image]

I need to know how to copy white balance settings and apply them to another file. I found only possibility to register "click white balance" profile. If DPP 4 can't, is there any 3rd party software that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the software is very, very limited. Doing what you want, is a very manual task. You can switch the dropdown from from `auto` to `color temperature`. This should display an absolute value for the current image (albeit not the current one). Set it to the point which looks ok, then  take a note of the value.

**Starting Point for manual WB**
[image: Color Temp Table]
Source: Wikipedia

Now go to the image you want to correct and manually set the color temperature to the same value. They should line up now. If not, then the `tint` also needs to be adjusted. You can do that with the fine-tune slider `M-------G`.

Almost every raw developing software can do this easier. I am using lightroom, which always shows the absolute values for color temperature as well as tint and makes it easy to copy these to other images.

If you want to invest some money, I can recommend Lightroom, Capture One and Luminar. If you are on a budget, Darktable is available for a lot of systems and is open source. https://www.darktable.org/

Comment: Changing WB mode from "Auto" to "Color temperature" does not show the exact value but switches the white balance to predefined value of 4400K. In the "Exif info" window the only information about white balance is "White Balance Mode: Auto". So I cannot retrieve the exact value in Kelvins.

Comment: You can however set it to a exact number, so if you start at 5600 you can at least have the two images to be the same. ;o(

Comment: Revised the answer and added some alternative software choices...

Comment: When the camera evaluates the white balance it not only sets the light temperature in Kelvins but also performs another tweaks. For example, with my lens and camera (7D mk II) I often get a green cast with predefined WB modes such as Sun and Cloudy. In other hand Auto Mode results natural colors. That's why I need to copy and apply exact WB settings.

Comment: Then you are way better off by ditching the software and trying some of the alternatives. They also offer way more ways to improve image quality, apply color grading, remove blemishes etc. After all, a tool should support you - not create additional work.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know how to copy white balance settings and apply them to another file.

Can do this by selecting 'Select and copy recipe settings...' from context menu (after right clicking on a raw file), then choosing 'White balance', the micro adjustment is shown highlighted,

[image]

The copied recipe can then be applied to more than one file - by selecting target files, and selecting 'Paste recipe' from context menu.

Comment: Copying recipe does not apply exact white balance evaluation results from source file to target, this only tells software to perform Auto white balance calculations on target image.But as I mentioned in question, 'Auto' gives reddish picture for second image.

Comment: @YuryRudakou You're right, 'Auto' doesn't expand before copy. May be change from 'Auto' to 'Color temperature' with 'Fine tune' to match the look of 'Auto' before copy? Will be tedious for sure...